# Количество комментариев

Tags: mysqli, php

Как определить сколько комментариев у видео?

то есть у меня есть список видео:

видео 1 
комментариев: n
видео 2 
комментариев: n
видео 3 
комментариев: n
видео 4 ...
комментариев: n

как мне вывести из таблицы `comment` количество комментариев у каждого видео? 
то есть вместо n число комментариев у всех видео.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM comment GROUP BY video_id;

Comment: А поподробнее?

Comment: а вопрос подробнее?

Comment: Ну я не совсем понимаю запрос, а точнее GROUP by video_id 
откуда мы взяли video_id если у меня 2 таблицы 
videos - сами видеозаписи
comment - комментарии к ним
в запросе данном выше я вижу только таблицу comment.

Comment: А подробнее нужно открывать книгу по SQL и читать. т.к. научиться программировать по вопроса будет очень сложно.

Comment: я знаю все и читал, просто забыл все уже как 2 года не программировал после службы.

Comment: что еще раз доказывает - армия в 18 лет - преступление против разума.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT v.id "id video", COUNT(*) "count comments" FROM videos v JOIN comments c ON v.id = c.video_id GROUP BY c.video_id;
```

Пример на [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fbff/2)

Comment: в комментарии у вас более правильный вариант. таблица videos не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

```
select nameVideo.table_video, (select count(*) from table_comment where table_comment.videoID = table_video.videoID) as countComment from table_video
```

Как то так. Почитайте для общего развития - [Вложенные SELECTы](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/ANSI_diff_Sub-selects.html)  и [Подсчет строк](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Counting_rows.html)

Comment: Не, вложенный запрос здесь лишнее.

Comment: $sql = "Select * from `videos`";
$query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

   echo $row["title"]. '<br />';
   echo $row["video"]. '<br />';
     
     //etc info videos 
        
         echo "comments:". N; 

}
 - Всего сейчас 3 записи в базе (в таблице videos) 
 - где N там количество комментариев у каждой записи. 
 - Комментарии к видео у меня выводяться по ид. 
 - то есть если www.stie.ru?video.php?watch=ID 
 - где ID там ид той записи которую хочу просмотреть.
и комментарии выводятся, WHERE `to_video` = 'ID'
 
 вот мне нужно узнать N.

Comment: Уточните структуру таблиц. Если количество комментариев уже хранится, то в какой именно таблице? Если в той же таблице где и информация о видео с именем поля N, то просто используйте в выводе $row["N"].